# Kubernetes Multiple Service Conflict

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I'm newbie in Kubernetes. I created a Kubernetes Cluster on Amazon [EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/).
I'm trying to setup multiple kubernetes services to run multiple ASP.NET applications in one cluster. But facing a weird problem.

Everything runs fine when there is only 1 service. But whenever i create 2nd service for 2nd application it creates a conflict. The conflict is sometime service 1 url load service 2 application and sometime it loads service 1 application and same happens with service 2 url on simple page reload.

I've tried both Amazon Classic ELB (With LoadBalancer Service Type) and Nginx Ingress controller (With ClusterIp Service Type). This error is common in both approaches.

Both services and deployments are running on port 80, I even tried different ports for both services and deployments to avoid port conflict but same problem.

I've checked the deployment & service status, and pod log everything looks fine. No error or warning at all

Please guide how i can fix this error.
Here is the yaml file of both services for nginx ingress

```
# Service 1 for deployment 1 (container port: 1120)
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-12-05T14:54:21Z
  labels:
    run: load-balancer-example
  name: app1-svc
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "463919"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/app1-svc
  uid: a*****-****-****-****-**********c
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.100.102.224
  ports:
  - port: 1120
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 1120
  selector:
    run: load-balancer-example
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

2nd Service

```
# Service 2 for deployment 2 (container port: 80)
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-12-05T10:13:33Z
  labels:
    run: load-balancer-example
  name: app2-svc
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "437188"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/app2-svc
  uid: 6******-****-****-****-************0
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.100.65.46
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    run: load-balancer-example
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide service yamls?

Comment: Thanks for response. Here is the command i used to create service.



`kubectl expose deployment app1-deployment --type=ClusterIP --name=app1-svc`

Comment: The things i want to know the label selector used in services and deployments. That's why asked for yamls, not command.

Comment: Sorry i just updated question with yamls. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the **selector** in the services. They both have the same **selector** and that's why you are facing that problem. So they both will point to same set of pods.

> The set of Pods targeted by a Service is (usually) determined by a Label Selector

Since deployemnt 1 and deployment 2 are different(i think), you should use different selector in them. Then expose the deployments. For example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.15.4
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

--

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-deployment
  labels:
    app: hello
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello
        image: nightfury1204/hello_server
        args:
        - serve
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

Above two deployment `nginx-deployment` and `hello-deployment` has different selector. So expose them to service will not colide each other.

When you use `kubectl expose deployment app1-deployment --type=ClusterIP --name=app1-svc` to expose deployment, the service will have the same selector as the deployment.

Comment: Thank you so much for your brief answer. It really helped. Really really appreciate it. Thanks again :-)
Cheers